# Java Weka prediction throws Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 22, Size: 22

Tags: java, weka

I am trying to train a classifier on labeled data (data with the outcome vector included) and run predictions on unlabeled data using the Weka library in Java.

I've investigated every case I can find online of someone receiving the error

> `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`

when doing this and they seem to all be caused by either

- a mis-match between the training and prediction data structures or
- improperly handled missing values

The solution to the first cause is to make the data structures match and verify this with `train.equalHeaders(test))`. As far as I can tell the data structures are an exact match and the result of `equalHeaders` is `true`. There is no missing data in the data sets I've been using for development / testing.

My training data is the famous iris data set, which I produced by using the copy that's built into R by calling `data(iris); write.csv(iris, "iris.csv", row.names = F)`. My prediction (test) data is the exact same data set, with the last column removed to simulate unlabeled test data. I've tried reading these files as .csv and from SQL Server tables and have encountered the same result.

I have tried 2 different ways of running the predictions; the way that's currently uncommented and the `.evaluateModel` method, both of which have the same error.

I have also tried changing the algorithm but this does not affect the error.

I have also printed the data to the screen and examined all of the available summary / diagnostic methods, all of which look as they should be.

The key part of my code is as follows. *Originally I posted the entire code, so if you'd like to see that it's available in the edit history*.

```
        //Add dummy outcome attribute to make shape match training
        Add filter1;
        filter1 = new Add();
        filter1.setAttributeIndex("last");
        filter1.setNominalLabels("'\"setosa\"','\"versicolor\"','\"virginica\"'");
        filter1.setAttributeName("\"Species\"");
        filter1.setInputFormat(test);
        test = Filter.useFilter(test, filter1);                    
        Instances newTest = Filter.useFilter(test, filter);    // create new test set

        // set class attribute
        newTest.setClassIndex(newTest.numAttributes() - 1);

        // create copy
        Instances labeled = new Instances(newTest);

        System.out.println("check headers: " + newTrain.equalHeaders(newTest));

        System.out.println(newTest); // throws the error if included
        // label instances
        for (int i = 0; i < newTest.numInstances(); i++) { // properly indexed
          System.out.println(i);
          double clsLabel = rf.classifyInstance(newTest.instance(i)); //throws the error if the earlier print is not included
          labeled.instance(i).setClassValue(clsLabel);
        } 

    }      
}
```

The full error is:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 22, Size: 22
>   java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
>   java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
>   weka.core.Attribute.value(Attribute.java:735)
>   weka.core.AbstractInstance.stringValue(AbstractInstance.java:668)
>   weka.core.AbstractInstance.stringValue(AbstractInstance.java:644)
>   weka.core.AbstractInstance.toString(AbstractInstance.java:756)
>   weka.core.DenseInstance.toStringNoWeight(DenseInstance.java:330)
>   weka.core.AbstractInstance.toStringMaxDecimalDigits(AbstractInstance.java:692)
>   weka.core.AbstractInstance.toString(AbstractInstance.java:712)
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2981)
>   java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:265)
>   weka.core.Instances.stringWithoutHeader(Instances.java:1734)
>   weka.core.Instances.toString(Instances.java:1718)
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2981)
>   java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:821)
>   weka.core.Tee.println(Tee.java:484)
>   myWeka.myWeka.main(myWeka.java:262)
>
>   at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
>   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
>   at weka.core.Attribute.value(Attribute.java:735)
>   at weka.core.AbstractInstance.stringValue(AbstractInstance.java:668)
>   at weka.core.AbstractInstance.stringValue(AbstractInstance.java:644)
>   at weka.core.AbstractInstance.toString(AbstractInstance.java:756)
>   at weka.core.DenseInstance.toStringNoWeight(DenseInstance.java:330)
>   at weka.core.AbstractInstance.toStringMaxDecimalDigits(AbstractInstance.java:692)
>   at weka.core.AbstractInstance.toString(AbstractInstance.java:712)
>   at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2981)
>   at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:265)
>   at weka.core.Instances.stringWithoutHeader(Instances.java:1734)
>   at weka.core.Instances.toString(Instances.java:1718)
>   at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2981)
>   at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:821)
>   at weka.core.Tee.println(Tee.java:484)
>   at myWeka.myWeka.main(myWeka.java:262)
> C:\Users\eggwhite\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
> ```
>
> Java returned: 1
>       BUILD FAILED (total time: 23 seconds)

The error  is thrown by `double clsLabel = rf.classifyInstance(newTest.instance(i));` unless I include the line `System.out.println(newTest);` for diagnostic purposes, in which case the same error is thrown by that line.

Comment: please, tell us the line throwing the Exception, your question is hard with so many code

Comment: @joc It is thrown by `double clsLabel = rf.classifyInstance(newTest.instance(i));` unless I include the line `System.out.println(newTest);` for diagnostic purposes, in which case the same error is thrown by that line. I can remove some of the code if that helps.

Comment: you can debug the code, problem seems to be in `newTest` because is the common part in both lines you tried. I bet `for (int i = 0; i < newTest.numInstances() - 1; i++) {` will do the job, because it wont try to access a missing index... but I must see code of `numInstances()` to tell you if is the right fix or not

Comment: @joc Thanks. I actually tried that yesterday, but it doesn't affect the error. The for loop is already set up for zero-indexing. Also the error wouldn't be thrown by the other prediction method or by `System.out.println(newTest)` if that were the case. What do you mean about missing code? The full code is still available in the edit history. It's actually reproducible -- you can run this with the iris data set or any arbitrary data set and get the same result.

Comment: i don't know if its the similar problem but i  faced an `IndexOutOfBoundException` when i used `add` or `addAll` to add more instances to my training set. Check here for more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460698/indexoutofboundsexception-when-trying-to-add-more-instances-to-training-set-usin

Comment: @xro7 Very interesting. Though I don't think the cause is exactly the same (because the only "add" in my code is `Add filter1` and I got the same error without that part using a different version of the prediction data) I wonder if part of your solution may help. On the post linked in your post I see something about using the same `arff` file for 2 data sets. Is it possible for me to use the `arff` header from my training data but to populate it with my testing data? How do you know how many lines long the `arff` header is (is there a programmatic way)?

Comment: Not sure what  are you asking exactly but you can create Instances from the same `arff` and then split the Instances into two by using `Instances newInstances = new Instances(originalInstances,startIndex,length)` So you can have an `arff` with training and test data and use `Instances training = new Instances(originalInstances,0,lengthOfTrainiingData)` and  `Instances test = new Instances(originalInstances,lengthOfTrainiingData,lengthOfOriginalInstances)`